# Json invoke not working after moving to mvc5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Same code stopped working after move to mvc5. In the following code I am trying to get cities for a country which is chosen in a dropdownlist using json.

The View.cshtml

```
  @Html.DropDownList("CountryId", (SelectList)ViewBag.Countries, " -- choose a country -- ", new { onchange = "CountryDDLChanged()", @class = "form-control" })
```

JavaScript file (a part of the code)

```
function CountryDDLChanged() {
  var url1 = "../Country/GetCitiesByCountryId";
  var countryid = $("#CountryId").val();

   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: url1,
     data: { countryId: countryid },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (result) {
       alert("yes");
     },
     error: function(req, status, error){
       alert(error);
     }
  });
}
```

CountryController

```
 public JsonResult GetCitiesByCountryId(int countryId)
 {
     JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
     using (var db = new DBContext())
     {
         List<City> cities = db.Cities.Where(c => c.CountryId == countryId).ToList();
         result.Data = cities;
         result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
     }
     return result;
 }
```

When I digg down in the code and debugging it. it generates this error.
`he ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.`
Why this works in MVC4 but not in MVC5? is it because of different version of EF?
how can I solve it?

UPDATED: Here is my Country Entithy and City :

```
[Table("Country")]
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public virtual List<MemberFee> MemberFees { get; set; }
}

 [Table("City")]
public class City
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think this might be something to do with your `DBContext` and the way you configure the `DbSets` and share the different contexts between the application.

Comment: @user217648 Does your `City` model contains a related entity e.g. another model as property?

Comment: Can you show your `City` model?

Comment: I have updated with Country Model (entity).